# Why does iChat Server keep connecting to proxy.eu.jabber.org?

Tags: xmpp, mac-osx-server

I have OS X Server 10.6.5 running on a new Mac Mini (server model), serving several functions among which is iChat Server (iChat and Pidgin on Windows as clients).  In the iChat log in Server Admin, I kept seeing entries about connecting to proxy.eu.jabber.org.  It's for our office network and I wasn't excited about external access to it, so I disabled server-to-server XMPP federation and now the connections just time out.  But why is it doing that in the first place?

Sample log entry:

```
(datetime) (servername)jabberd/resolver[portnum]: [xmpp-server._tcp.proxy.eu.jabber.org resolved to 208.68.163.220:5269 (300 seconds to live)
```

then:

```
sending dialback auth request for route '(full server hostname)/proxy.eu.jabber.org'
```

A couple minutes later, it comes back with:

```
dialback for outgoing route '(full server hostname)/proxy.eu.jabber.org' timed out
```

Comment: Does it try to connect when no users are connected to your machine? It might be a client configuration issue, as you either connect because of proxied file transfers, or because of server to server communication.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be user-dependent, no.  It seems like it's just trying to network itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to iChat bridging your jabber server to the jabber network in order to be able to talk to other jabber users, its configured to do so by default.

Comment: So it's trying to join itself to a larger jabber network...that makes sense.  I'm just a little surprised that after I disable that (server-to-server federation?) it keeps trying and timing out, instead of just stopping altogether.

Comment: Yeah, Mac OS X server is surprisingly dodgy on some aspects, I'm pretty sure that it still tries to connect but disabling the option just makes it not register itself into the list of available servers. Sometimes the best option is just editing the conf files by hand.